# Redis 7.0 - OpenSSL version?

Tags: c, redis, openssl

Does Redis 7.0 support OpenSSL 3.0?  I'm trying to compile and link Redis 7.0 with the libssl shared library from OpenSSL 3.0.  However, it's complaining about missing references:

```
    .
    .
    .
    CC script.o
    CC functions.o
    CC function_lua.o
    CC commands.o
    LINK redis-server
tls.o: In function `createSSLContext':
/home/user1/redis-stable/src/tls.c:213: undefined reference to `TLS_method'
/home/user1/redis-stable/src/tls.c:215: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_set_options'
/home/user1/redis-stable/src/tls.c:218: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_set_options'
/home/user1/redis-stable/src/tls.c:235: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_set_options'
/home/user1/redis-stable/src/tls.c:269: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_set_ciphersuites'
/home/user1/redis-stable/src/tls.c:231: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_set_options'
/home/user1/redis-stable/src/tls.c:222: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_set_options'
/home/user1/redis-stable/src/tls.c:224: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_set_options'
/home/user1/redis-stable/src/tls.c:227: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_set_options'
tls.o: In function `tlsInit':
/home/user1/redis-stable/src/tls.c:158: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_init_crypto'
tls.o: In function `tlsConfigure':
/home/user1/redis-stable/src/tls.c:332: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_set_options'
/home/user1/redis-stable/src/tls.c:343: undefined reference to `OSSL_DECODER_CTX_new_for_pkey'
/home/user1/redis-stable/src/tls.c:350: undefined reference to `OSSL_DECODER_from_fp'
/home/user1/redis-stable/src/tls.c:352: undefined reference to `OSSL_DECODER_CTX_free'
/home/user1/redis-stable/src/tls.c:327: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_set_options'
/home/user1/redis-stable/src/tls.c:357: undefined reference to `OSSL_DECODER_CTX_free'
/home/user1/redis-stable/src/tls.c:360: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_set0_tmp_dh_pkey'
tls.o: In function `connTLSGetPeerCert':
/home/user1/redis-stable/src/tls.c:1060: undefined reference to `SSL_get1_peer_certificate'
tls.o: In function `tlsCleanup':
/home/user1/redis-stable/src/tls.c:184: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_cleanup'
../deps/hiredis/libhiredis_ssl.a(ssl.o): In function `redisInitOpenSSL':
/home/user1/redis-stable/deps/hiredis/ssl.c:159: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_init_ssl'
../deps/hiredis/libhiredis_ssl.a(ssl.o): In function `redisCreateSSLContext':
/home/user1/redis-stable/deps/hiredis/ssl.c:231: undefined reference to `TLS_client_method'
/home/user1/redis-stable/deps/hiredis/ssl.c:237: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_set_options'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [redis-server] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user1/redis-stable/src'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: I just picked Redis 7.0.4 source and built against OpenSSL 3.0.5, so I gotta assume yes, it's supported.  When you did your build did you (a) use `BUILD_TLS=yes`, and (b) use `OPENSSL_PREFIX=/path/to/your/openssl/dist` ? Sorry for asking, but I didn't see the build commands you used in your post, notably because for whatever reason you didn't bother to include them.

Comment: @WhozCraig, thanks for the reply.  The build command I ran was `make BUILD_TLS=yes  OPENSSL_PREFIX=/usr/local`.  Both the _libssl.so.3_ and _libcrypto.so.3_ dynamic shared  libraries are located in the **/usr/local/lib64** directory.  I ended up having to update the Redis Makefile and change `OPENSSL_LDFLAGS=-L$(OPENSSL_PREFIX)/lib` to `OPENSSL_LDFLAGS=-L$(OPENSSL_PREFIX)/lib64` in order to get the linking phase to be successful.  Sorry, I don't have a lot of experience building large C applications from source but am trying to learn.  Thanks again for your reply.

Comment: Glad you got it to work. That's an unusual anatomy for an openssl configuration. I would expect /usr/local/include and /usr/local/lib, and obviously so does the redis build.